# Node set variable from text file

Tags: node.js

I am working on oauth2 for an API client, and I am having trouble getting the promise back in time to continue with the other calls to the API.  My tokens expire every 30 minutes and my node runs every 10 minutes.  I thought I could set a text file to the newest token each time the script runs, and grab it at the beginning and always have a good token to use for auth.  The variable doesn't get set in time to make the calls, so the header has undefined next the Bearer.  I can't figure out how to get the variable set before the call goes off.

Here is the script I am using to make the calls

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Axios = require("axios");
const moment = require("moment");
const config = require("../config/default");
const oauth = require("axios-oauth-client");
const fs = require('fs');
let accessToken;
var token = fs.readFile('token.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return data;
    });


const getOwnerCredentials = oauth.client(Axios.create(), {
  url: 'url',
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: 'username',
  client_secret: 'secret',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  scope: 'scope'
  });

const tokenCall = async () => { 
    const result = await getOwnerCredentials();
    return result
}

const getToken = async () => {
    const accessToken = await tokenCall();
    const fs = require('fs')
    fs.writeFile('/root/qt-cwsedona/token.txt', '', function(){console.log('done')})    
    fs.writeFile('token.txt', accessToken.access_token, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });

    
};


getToken();




class Sedona {
    constructor() {
        this.baseUrl = config.sedonaUrl;    
    this.client = Axios.default.create({

            baseURL: this.baseUrl,
            auth: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    
    },

        });

    console.log(this.client);
    }
  

    getCustomerBillId(customer_id) {
        return this.client.get('/CustomerBill/' + customer_id).then(response => {
            let result = parseInt(response['data'][0]['CustomerBillId']);
            if (isNaN(result)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                return result.toString();
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
    }
```

Then I am this code to actually kick off these functions

```
const Sedona = require("./services/SedonaService");
Promise.all([
                                    sedona.getCustomerBillId(customerId)
                                
                                
                            ]).then(sedona_results => {
```

Comment: What mechanism do you use for executing code every 10 minutes? Is it a cron job, or it is a single process with some kind of timers, or?

Comment: I am using node-schedule to run every 10 minutes 
const Scheduler = require("node-schedule");

Scheduler.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * *', function () {
    Main.default.perform();
});

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right way to do this, but I was able to set the default header for axios in the async function and it worked.

```
const getToken = async () => {
    const accessToken = await tokenCall();
    const token = accessToken.access_token;
    Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+accessToken.access_token;
    
};
```